# How can I reach my own network while using ICS on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, connection-sharing

**The Setup**

I recently got my laptop into a shared internet connection with my home-pc - the setup looks like this:

```
laptop.wlan 192.168.0.10 -> pc.wlan 192.168.0.5 -> pc.lan 192.168.0.9 -> router 192.168.0.1

laptop.dns 192.168.0.5 | pc.wlan.dns --- | pc.lan.dns 192.168.0.1

laptop.gw 192.168.0.5 | pc.wlan.gw --- | pc.lan.gw 192.168.0.1
```

the pc.lan has ICS enabled and every pre-added protocol activated.

- I get Internet, whitout any problems.
- I can ping and remotedesktop to the shared pc

**The Problem**

- I cannot ping or connect to my gateway on ...0.1 -> why?!

My feeling is, that this is intentionall, although it is the same network and subnet and the laptop has joined to the homenet-group. Firewalls are off.

If it is intentionall is there ANY way to use my pc as a network-access-point, so that my laptop can connect to my network and the internet? Of course I could try to VPN my way back in, but this would be strange o_O

Maybe I just made a studip mistake (it's quite late), feel free to point it out - thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have a network conflict because your using the same ip range for both networks. The default IP range for ICS is 192.168.0.1 you can either change your network settings on your router or you can try to follow this link http://m.geekzone.co.nz/Forums/66/Topic/9625.

Comment: interesting stuff about the NAT32 and so, but no solution here - follwing some links to this nice qoute: "Some of the answers from MS employees on Technet absolutely astound me to be honest. [...] He said that it's not possible to bridge the virtual AP to another network. Yes, this is by "design" [...]"

Comment: BTW, I don't think there is an IP-Conflict, as the Internet-Connetcion is working properly, only connections to my own homenetwork are unreachable - it seems this is by design ... using the same IP range is not the problem, as long as you do not use the same IPs, which I don't.